# Code will not run. clearInterval move heading in a square

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make the heading move in a square and make it so that when i click on the heading, the movement stops. All while only using javascript and JQuery. Right now the heading shows but it doesnt move at all. if anybody knows how to make this work please help.

```
<h1 id="heading" style="position:absolute;">Watch the moving heading!</h1>
```

```js
function move() {
    $("h1").animate({
        "left": "+=200px"
    }, "slow").animate({
        "top": "+=200px"
    }, "slow").animate({
        "left": "-=200px"
    }, "slow").animate({
        "top": "-=200px"
    }, "slow", function() {
        var interval = setInterval(move(), 300);
        interval
    });
}

var setinterval = setInterval(move(), 300);

//this should stop it
$("h1").click(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    $('h1').stop();
}
```

Comment: `setInterval(move, 300)`. In your code you're immediately calling the function rather than passing in the reference to it. Remove the random mention of `interval`, and declare `var interval` as a global, not within the function otherwise other functions can't access it.

Comment: You forgot a ")" at the end of the script.

close the `$("h1").click( ...` with a `)`

Comment: And there's an `interval` variable loose in the animate callback function..

Comment: Try to use https://jsfiddle.net/ please

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's a bunch of things wrong. I'll go over them in a little detail, but in the meantime here's the correct code:

```
function move() {
    $("h1").animate({
        "left": "+=200px"
    }, "slow").animate({
        "top": "+=200px"
    }, "slow").animate({
        "left": "-=200px"
    }, "slow").animate({
        "top": "-=200px"
    });
}

var interval = setInterval(move, 300);

//this should stop it
$("h1").click(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    $(this).stop(true, true);
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/95jdfw6o/10/)

So:

1) Globally declare your `interval` variable. It won't work if you declare it in a function because then other functions can't access it. But that doesn't matter because of 2).

2) Remove the `setInterval` from the `move` function.

3) Pass in a reference to `move` to `setInterval`, don't call it: `setInterval(move, 300);`

4) Watch your closing brackets and braces.

5) `.stop` needs its `clearQueue` property to be set to `true` otherwise it will only stop the last animation in the queue, and you have many.

Answer (score 0):

The issue (aside from the mis-matched brackets) is because your `setInterval()` call is stacking up the animations on the queue, hence by the time you actually clear the queue several thousand `animate()` calls are queued up and will complete.

You can change your logic so that there is no need to use a timer at all by recursively calling `move()` and setting a flag on the `h1` on click which will stop the animation after the next loop. Try this:

```
function move() {
    $("h1").animate({
        "left": "+=200px"
    }, "slow").animate({
        "top": "+=200px"
    }, "slow").animate({
        "left": "-=200px"
    }, "slow").animate({
        "top": "-=200px"
    }, "slow", function() {
        !$(this).data('stop') && move();
    });
}

move();

$("h1").click(function() {
    $(this).data('stop', true);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/c6j82fwz/)

If required you could use this pattern to make the click of the `h1` a toggle on the animation:

```
$("h1").click(function() {
    var stop = $(this).data('stop');
    if (stop)
        move();

    $(this).data('stop', !stop);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/c6j82fwz/1/)